# Xamarin: Create a custom grid View

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, android-gridview

I need create a custom GridView in Android Application (Dev. on VS2012 with Xamarin plugin). 
I need on each cell  a image and label text.

This example work perfectly, but has not a text label.
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/grid_view/

I need anything how this:
[Custom Grid View {Image+Text}](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-nCDvyS6U0ns/UfCu2GxB-3I/AAAAAAAAAvQ/muREYvnb7m4/s1600/Screenshot_2013-07-25-10-10-14.png)

but I only found Java Examples.
Please Help me

PD: Sorry by Image, but I can't upload images (I need more reputation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new layout that has the ImageView & TextView. Then, in the `GetView` method of the `ImageAdapter` class, inflate that layout and populate it, for example:

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view;

    if (convertView == null) 
    {  
        view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_grid_row, parent, false);
    }
    else
    {
        view = convertView;
    }


    var imageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.my_image_view);
    imageView.SetImageResource (thumbIds[position]);

    var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.my_text_view);
    textView.Text = "Text to Display";

    return view;
}
```

**Edit:** (Add to Code "(" and ";")

**Update:** Here is a sample layout file, `my_grid_row.axml`, that is inflated by the `GetView` method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/my_image_vieww" />
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I have a question: Need create a .axml from one cell and the .axml from the gridview?

Comment: Just one .AXML will do, for the row. You could probably use a LinearLayout to hold your ImageView and TextView.

Comment: Can you help me with other problem in the custom gridview? Thanks