# Xamarin Visual Studio 2017 Gridview with images and textview

Tags: gridview, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to populate a gridview with images and text.  First I got the code to work with just the images (12 images).  That image adapter code is:

```
class ImageAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    public DataSet participants;
    public User MyUser;
    private readonly Context context;


public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
        context = c;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return participants.Tables[0].Rows.Count; }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return  null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.LayoutParameters = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(340, 340);
            imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
            imageView.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else
        {
            imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }
        string participantid = participants.Tables[0].Rows[position][0].ToString();
        myservice.aservice myService = new service;
        DataSet MyPhotoDataSet = myService.GetPhoto(MyUser.Username, MyUser.Password, participantid );
        byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])MyPhotoDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        // imageView.SetImageResource(thumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

This works with no issues.  I get all images displayed in the gridview.  I needed to add a textview to go with each image in the cell and used the code at the following link as a guide: [Xamarin: Create a custom grid View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464775/xamarin-create-a-custom-grid-view)

I changed GetView to this:

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

            view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Cellview, parent, false);

        }
        else
        {
            view = convertView;
        }

        var myimageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.my_image_vieww);
        var textview = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.my_text_view);

        myimageView.LayoutParameters = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(340, 340);
        myimageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
        myimageView.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);


        string participantid = participants.Tables[0].Rows[position][0].ToString();
        myservice.aservice myService = new service;
        DataSet MyPhotoDataSet = myService.GetPhoto(MyUser.Username, MyUser.Password, participantid );
        byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])MyPhotoDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        myimageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        textview.Text = participants.Tables[0].Rows[position][1].ToString();
        // imageView.SetImageResource(thumbIds[position]);
        return myimageView;
    }
}
```

This is the Cellview.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/my_image_vieww" />
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The first time through no issues, on the second execution `convertview` is not null and the `view = convertView` line is executed, which is the same as the "just images version".  At that point the line `textview = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.my_text_view)` returns null and I can't figure out why.  What am I missing?

Comment: All you need is a clean build after deleting the bin and obj files if i am not wrong, also in your getView method textview declaration it would be better if your textview was defined inside the method something like `var textview = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.my_text_view);`

Comment: Ah ... textview is defined in the method, somehow that line got deleted ... I'll edit the question.  The `var` portion got deleted.  Thanks.

Comment: A clean and rebuild of the project did not work.  :(

Comment: Do one thing open the `ResourceDesigner.cs` file and search for `my_text_view` and see if the dynamic `int` value was defined or not also your Xamarin.Android and Visual studio details would help

Comment: And also your ImageView's LayoutParams should have linear layout params and not absListView something like this: `myimageView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(340, 340);`

Comment: You could try to put ` var myimageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.my_image_vieww);
        var textview = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.my_text_view);` in the `if (convertView == null) {....}` like this link.https://www.viralandroid.com/2016/04/android-gridview-with-image-and-text.html

Comment: @G.hakim Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.7 (latest version), Xamarin v4.12.3.80 (also latest version).  I will change the layout parameters, didn't notice that as the layout is linear.  @Leon Lu, an inspection of the `view` object in the debugger indicates that the textview was not part of it when `convertView` is not null.  I wll try creating/inflating the view regardless if convertView is null or not, but I would expect that would not work.

Comment: @G.hakim an inspection of the `ResourcesDesigner.cs` file revealed that `my_text_view` is defined.

Comment: @G.hakim changing the layout parameters to linear did not have any effect.  :(

Comment: Can you check one more thing? Check if the View's children include a textview or not

Comment: I had done that, when `currentView` is null and I inflate using the xml, all views are there.  When `currentView` is not null, only the image view is there.  I placed an `if` statement around the `textview.Text =` code to check for null so that the code would run.  All that I get are the images no text.  Even with the first image.  The `textview` just disappears.

Comment: UPDATE:

I changed the code so that the line `view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Cellview, parent, false);` is executed whether or not `convertView` is null or not.  Now `textview` is never null, but all I get are the images, no textview.  Bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... after some research (http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) and suggestions from a lot of people, I got something together that works very nicely.  I changed the GetView Method to:

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        View gridView;
        gridView = new View(context);
        gridView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Cellview, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView)gridView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.my_text_view);
        textView.Text = participants.Tables[0].Rows[position][1].ToString();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)gridView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.my_image_view);
        byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])participants.Tables[0].Rows[position][2];
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return gridView;
    }
```

I also changed the Cellview.xml slightly to:

```
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="250dp"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:id="@+id/my_image_view" />

   <TextView
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"    
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingTop="20px"
      android:id="@+id/my_text_view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Got a nice responsive display.  My thanks to everyone who helped.